# android 6.0 javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT

Tags: android, encryption, android-6.0-marshmallow, badpaddingexception

this code works well before android 6.0, **but get an error on 6.0 if encrypted file size less than about 1k bytes.**

```
public static byte[] decode(byte[] decrypteSrcBuffer) throws Exception {
    Key deskey = null;
    DESedeKeySpec spec = new DESedeKeySpec(mKeyBytes);
    SecretKeyFactory keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("desede");
    deskey = keyfactory.generateSecret(spec);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("desede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, deskey, ips);
    byte[] decryptData = cipher.doFinal(decrypteSrcBuffer);

    return decryptData;
}
```

Error info:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.EVP_CipherFinal_ex(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher$EVP_CIPHER.doFinalInternal(OpenSSLCipher.java:568)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipher.java:350)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2056)
```

Comment: It means that either your ciphertext or your key are wrong. Check your encodings of everything. This code itself is "correct". The issue is somewhere else. Please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifyable example](/help/mcve).

Comment: **Don't use Triple DES nowadays.** It only provides at best 112 bit of security even if you use the largest key size of 192 bit. If a shorter key size is used, then it only provides 56 or 57 bits of security. AES would be faster (processors have a special AES-NI instruction set) and even more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with 3DES. See [Security comparison of 3DES and AES](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).

Comment: The IV must be unpredictable (read: random). Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

Comment: I had this as as others said "either your ciphertext or your key are wrong"  and turn out I'd forgotten to decode me key from base64 i'd just done string.getBytes().

Comment: In my case this error only occur when my device running out of memory.

Comment: I have same issue while encrypting mp3 file in honor  device(OS: Orio).
 
  

while ((readLength = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buff, 0, readLength);
            }





after write in to outputStream it goes to Catch(message:javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT)

Comment: I have the same issue **my code works on JVM 8** but doesn't work on android. also I'm using **AES**

Comment: @scottyab Can you please show in code what you did to fix it? I might have the same issue.